# How to find the radius of convergence of different powers $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_{n} z^{2 n+2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

If I have a power series on the form $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} z^{n}$$ A theorem tells me it has a radius of convergence given by $$R=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left|\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}\right|$$

---

How can I use this formula to find the radius of convergence of a series with different powers? Consider fx. $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_{n} z^{2 n+2}$$

Is it possible to determine the radius of convergence of this series using the above formula? I don't have the ratio test at my disposal. If the power series just had even powers like $z^{2n}$ it could easily be shown that the radius of convergence would be $R=\sqrt{\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left|\frac{b_{n}}{b_{n+1}}\right|}$. But I don't know what to do with shifted powers.

Comment: @Desperado is that because u doesn't contain any n? and can thus be treated as a constant?

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting $z^{2n+2}=z^2(z^2)^n=z^2w^n$, if you get common factor $z^2$, you get as a result $z^2 \sum b_nw^n$

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do a relabeling of your coefficients to shift everything down 2.  For instance, let $c_0=c_1=0$ and $c_n=b_{n-2}$ for $n\geq 2$.   Then your series is the exact same as the series with terms $c_nz^{2n}$